# Validate answer to exact match in Google Forms

Tags: regex, google-forms

I'm trying to limit a answer in Google Forms to exact word without it continues. What I mean:

If input is: "word" it passes, but if it is "sample","words", "worda", and etc... "word*" it does not pass.

I tried with `(RegExr+?(?=\w|\d|\s))` ,   `/RegExr+?(?=\w|\d|\s)/` ,`RegExr+?(?=\w|\d|\s)` with RegEx menu and Match option, but it gives error that the changes can not be saved.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but i get the feeling you want something more complicated.  If you need something other than the solution posted, please update your question.

Comment: No, thank you a lot! That is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be overthinking this one.  The validator accepts a regular expression without any of the delimiters you're used to in, say, `sed` or `javascript`.  The basic regex `^word$` should do what you want (it did in my tests, below)
[image: simple regex validation in Google form]